# Crystal Report : Suppress certain section on the next page while printing

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm having problem to hide other section on the next page, what should I do if the highlight data above need to be hide/suppress on the next page while printing but still display it on the first page only. Then, I also confuse what was the difference between hide and suppress as well.

[image]

**Sorry for incorrect spelling in photo : Highlight text should hide in the next page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Section Expert you will want to use a formula in the "Suppress" property for the section or sections that print the highlighted text in your report.  The formula should be:

```
PageNumber > 1;
```

When writing a formula for a Suppress property the formula should always be an expression that evaluates to True or False.  When the expression is True the object will be suppressed.

Comment: Thank you in advance i will try shortly and let you know if it work.

Comment: if dont mind may you explain to me what was mean by `PageNumber<>TotalPageCount`

Comment: `PageNumber <> TotalPageCount` is a logical expression that would evaluate to true when the current Page Number does not equal the Total Number of Pages.  If used in a Suppress property for a section, it would only print that section on the last page, and only when there are more than 1 pages.  TotalPageCount is one of the special fields that prints the total number of pages in a report, but you should be aware if you have a section with "Reset Page Number After" property enabled you should watch how this impacts the total number of actual pages printed versus your design goals.